# How to change font size in emacs?

Tags: fonts, emacs

I download emacs with 'sudo apt-get install emacs'. When I run emacs, I see emacs with too big fonts. I don't know why the default setup to have normal font size in emacs. How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### The temporary solution

You can press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-+</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C--</kbd> to increase or decrease the buffer text size.

#### The permanent solution

Put the following in your `.emacs`-file:

```
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)
```

The value is in 1/10pt, so 100 will give you 10pt, etc.

Source: [How to set the font size in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs)

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different way to do the same thing, by setting botht the font and size in one go, again in the .emacs file. If you want to use a differing font check it exists first or you will get an error message.

(set-default-font "Monospace-12")

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the desired font size into `~/.Xresources`:

```
Emacs.default.attributeHeight: 94
```

as in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10439/5165 .

It will be read on the next session startup. To get those settings in the current session, you can do `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.